# Save RTSP video frames to a file

Tags: rtsp, live555

I am able to play rtsp stream on web page using live555 server but I need to extract the frames from the rtsp stream and store them in a file.
Can anyone guide me how to do this?

Comment: Did you look at ffmpeg?

Comment: What do you use on the client side (web page)?

Comment: I have used VLC plugin to display rtsp stream but this is not a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are already familiar with live555 try use simple RTSP client application which comes with live555 package. Application called **openRTSP** and located in **testProgs** folder. It could ready input RTSP stream and save to file.